# Hibernate batch insert not working as expected

Tags: java, hibernate, db2

I am using hibernate batch insert in for DB2, but not get it worked properly.

This is my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (IDENTIFIER VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, MESSAGE VARCHAR(10), CREATION_DATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP, CONSTRAINT MY__PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (IDENTIFIER));
```

I also have installed a trigger to test batching...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "NEW_ENTRY" 
BEFORE INSERT ON MY_TABLE 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN ATOMIC
            CALL dbms_alert.sleep(5);
        END
```

This is my implemenatation...

```
@Stateless
@Local
public class MyEntityImpl{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyEm")
    protected EntityManager em;

    public void batch() {
        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
            MyEntity newEntity = new MyEntity(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            newEntity.setMessage(Integer.toString(a));
            em.persist(newEntity);
        }
        em.flush();
        em.clear();
    }
}
```

This is my configuration in my persistence.xml...

```
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value = "true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value = "20"/>
    <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value = "true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value = "true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value = "thread"/>
```

So what I expect is nearly same creation dates, but got
[image]

This is my log output

```
batching 10 statements: 1: insert into MY_TABLE (CREATION_DATE, MESSAGE, IDENTIFIER) 
values ('11/29/2023 13:32:20.652', '0', '6cbda799-8c09-47d2-9b54-818ecc5963d9') 2: insert into 
MY_TABLE (CREATION_DATE, MESSAGE, IDENTIFIER) values ('11/29/2023 13:32:20.655', '1', 
'87332578-7ce3-4d7f-9e7f-adf761f07e35') 3: insert into MY_TABLE (CREATION_DATE, MESSAGE, 
IDENTIFIER) values ('11/29/2023 13:32:20.656', '2', '27e8612c-1db1-4832-b312-6b5b292441c6')
```

Comment: You are sleeping 5 seconds between each row (because your trigger is defined at row level).  Did you mean to instead defined the trigger at statement level (if the om is performing a block insert, as distinct from a row insert ) ??.  Otherwise you cannot use a DEFAULT value for the creation_date column and the application has to preset it to same value for all rows.

Comment: By presetting the date, it will have almost the same creation date. But it still takes 50s as without batching, why? I expect that it will be handled much more faster.

Comment: It seems you have not understood my previous comment concerning the granularity of the trigger (per row, or per statement), and whether or not your OM is using single-statement-multi-row insert versus row-by-row insert.

Comment: This trigger can also be defined on statement level. But I have some implemented triggers which made some checks on the inserted row which takes a few time. That's why I want to use batching here. So is it not possible to use batch insert with trigger definition at row level?